# Images with more info on the next page

Tags: php, image, html-table

The images are stored in my folder and not in database. When i click on one of the images, it will lead me to see more info on the next page. This would means that i can see the image with a bigger size.

How do I do this with less php pages created? Below are snippets of my codes

```
<table>
<tr> 
<th class="timgB"><h4><img src="city/GVcementMixture.jpg" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" title="Cement Mixture"/> Cement Mixture </a></h4></th>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: If you don't want to create new pages, then a pop up can be done using jquery, it is something called colorbox you should try!!

Comment: Your code's not valid. Missing a begin `a` tag.

Comment: are you want to show only single image with big size( 1. only single image on page or 2. along with other image with old size) or all the image in big size.

Comment: I found other site that gives me what I want. It's called zoomIt. Similarly, your suggestion helps me too! Thanks(: @Razor

Answer (score 0):

You *could* keep it all in one form/page with a big if/else or switch/case statement to evaluate the selected image and show only info pertaining to the selected image such as the full size image or a sub-set of child images. But it would be best presented in jQuery as @Razor said.

```
<form ...>
    <button type=submit name=imgID value=1>
    <button type=submit name=imgID value=2>
    ...

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['imgID'])):
        // Show info related to selected image
        ...
```

Comment: I found a site that gives me what I want. It's called zoomIt. It's quite similar with what Razor recommended. Thanks for replying(: @dirt

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this. use `class="small` for make image size small and `class="big-img"` to big size image. the `?img=img23.jpg` in your link decide which image should be shown with big size. or if you use thumbnail of image as small size and want to show a full size only when some one click on thumbnail then update the link in upper `div` (class="big-img") or leave comment.

//it will work as you want

```
<body>
    <div class = "big-img"> <!-- set class to show big size image-->
        <?php if(isset($_GET['img'])): ?>
            <img src="city/.<?php echo $_GET['img']; ?>" alt="">
        <?php endif; ?> 
    </div>
     <table>
        <tr><!-- set class to show small size image-->
            <td class = "small"><a href="?img=img23.jpg"><img src="city/img23.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
            <td class = "small"><a href="?img=img24.jpg"><img src="city/img24.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
            <td class = "small"><a href="?img=img25.jpg"><img src="city/img25.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</body>
```